# Proposition 1.7. (III) Conway's Functional Analysis

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

The following is from Conway's Functional Analysis:

[image]

Q1- Orange : To prove that $C_0(X)$ is a linear manifold in $C_b(X)$, one needs to prove that 1- $af \in C_0(X)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{F}$ and all $f \in C_0(X)$ and 2- $f+g \in C_0(X)$ for all $f,g \in C_0(X)$. "1" is easy. How to prove "2"?

Q2- Green : How the indicated inclusion implies $f \in C_0(X)$?

Q3- The book claims without a proof that if X is compact then $C_0(X)=C_b(X)=C(X)$ in which $C(X)$ is the set of continuous functions on X. How both equalities hold?

There are many definitions for locally compact space and the one I know is :

> For every point x of X, every neighbourhood of x contains a compact neighbourhood of x.

Comment: Regarding Q3: if $X$ is compact, then every continuous function is bounded, hence $C_b(X) = C(X)$. Moreover, the suppose of any function of $C(X)$ is a closed subset of $X$, which means that every continuous function has compact support, which means that $C_0(X) = C(X)$.

Comment: For Q1: show that the support of $f + g$ is necessarily a subset of the union of the supports of $f$ and $g$. From there, use the fact or show that the union of two compact sets is compact.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, About your first comment : how do you conclude that "every continuous function has compact support, which means that C_0(X)=C(X)"? About your second comment : I can't connect support of a function to the concepts introduced in the theorem and the book. :(

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your definition of $C_0(X)$ then?

Comment: @BenGrossmann, the proposition defines it :)

Comment: Of course, that was silly of me. I won't use it, but in case you're curious: the support of a function is the closure of the set $\{x \in X \mid f(x) \neq 0\}$. A function will be an element of $C_0$ iff its support is compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my convenience, I will use $S(f,\epsilon)$ to refer to the set $S(f,\epsilon) = \{x \in X : |f(x)| \geq \epsilon\}$.

Regarding Q1: suppose that $f,g \in C_0(X)$, and let $\epsilon > 0$. We note that for any $x \in X$,
$$
|f(x) + g(x)| \leq |f(x)| + |g(x)|.
$$
From this, we can can conclude that
$$
S(f+g,\epsilon) \subseteq S(f,\epsilon/2) \cup S(g,\epsilon/2).
$$
$S(f,\epsilon/2) \cup S(g,\epsilon/2)$ is a union of compact sets and is therefore compact. Thus, $S(f + g,\epsilon)$ is a closed subset of a compact set, which means that $S(f+g,\epsilon)$ is compact. $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, so we indeed have $f + g \in C_0(X)$.

Regarding Q2: $\{x \in X : |f(x)| \geq \epsilon\}$ is a closed subset of a compact set and is therefore compact.

Regarding Q3: if $X$ is compact, then every continuous function is bounded, hence $C_b(X) = C(X)$. Moreover, for any $\epsilon > 0$, the set $S(f,\epsilon)$ is a closed subset of the compact set $X$ and is therefore compact. So, $f \in C_0(X)$ and we indeed have $C(X) = C_0(X)$.

Comment: For Q1, it is not $\le$, it is $ge$! That's why I stuck in that. Also how the set in your answer for Q2 is closed when $ge$ is used not $\le$?

Comment: @L.G. Sorry for the typo. Regarding Q1: in order to have $|f(x) + g(x)| \geq \epsilon$, it must be the case that either $|f(x)| \geq \epsilon/2$ or $|g(x)| \geq \epsilon/2$. Otherwise, the triangle inequality implies that $|f(x) + g(x)| \leq |f(x)| + |g(x)| < \epsilon$. Regarding Q2: the fact that $x \mapsto |f(x)|$ is a continuous function means that $\{x \in X : |f(x)| \geq \epsilon\}$ is closed.

Comment: If for some x, |f(x)|=2ϵ/3 and |g(x)|=0 then |f(x)+g(x)|=2ϵ/3<ϵ and not ≥ϵ (?)

Comment: @L.G. I don't see the issue. If $|f(x) + g(x)| \geq \epsilon$, then it must hold that $|f(x)| \geq \epsilon/2$ or $|g(x)|\geq \epsilon/2$, but the converse to this statement doesn't hold.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ben :)